# Why router.post() doesn't assign any value to MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I am working on a small timer app but stuck with a part where router.post() has to assign value to MongoDB. The point is that data in MongoDB is created every time when the user presses the pause button but without values from Schema Module... There is only ID, createdAt and updatedAt coz of the timestamp from Module class. I tried to debug router.post() by simply adding console.log() :

```
router.post('/savetasks',  function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
// my logic.....
}
```

The result was an empty array :( Now I am assuming that maybe the problem is in the configuration of my module... Or the way of subscribing/streaming data.

router.post() method

```
router.post('/savetasks', async (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);
const { startTime, endTime, elapsedTime } = req.body;
const newTime = new Time({startTime, endTime, elapsedTime});
await newTime.save();

const token = jwt.sign({ _id: newTime._id}, 'secretkey');

res.status(200).json({token}); 

});
```

Time.js class

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const timeSchema = new Schema({
  startTime: String,
  endTime: String,
  elapsedTime: String
 }, {
 timestamps: true
 });

module.exports = model('Time', timeSchema);
```

HttpClient

```
postTasks(times) {
return this.httpClient.post(this.URL + '/savetasks', times);
}
```

The way I subscribe... it's called from pauseTimer() method

```
pauseTimer() {
clearInterval(this.interval);

this.endTime = new Date();
console.log(this.endTime);

this.elapsedTime = this.endTime - this.startTime
console.log(this.elapsedTime);

this.tasksService.postTasks(this.time)
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      this.time = res;
      //this.elapsed = res;
      console.log(this.time);
    },
    err => console.log(err)
  );
 }
```

Comment: What is the console.log printing ?

Comment: Kunal Mukherjee For the back-end it's an empty array. And for the front-end only the token {token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1Z…1NzV9.rItkiR4A2OC5OlW4uOlWCzRoNOlzKdyQGhyRoe7UmwM"}

Comment: I think the issue is with posting the data, change this line to - `this.tasksService.postTasks({
 startTime: this.startTime,
 endTime: this.endTime,
 elapsedTime: this.endTime - this.startTime
})`

Comment: Kunal Mukherjee definitely that was an issue, now it works :)))) Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @KunalMukherjee: Create an answer for this that the OP can accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data which you were posting to the back-end API was incorrect, as you were expecting an object with 3 properties - `startTime`, `endTime` and `elapsedTime`.

Fix your service code to -

```
pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);

    this.endTime = new Date();
    console.log(this.endTime);

    this.elapsedTime = this.endTime - this.startTime
    console.log(this.elapsedTime);

    const requestBody = {
        startTime: this.startTime,
        endTime: this.endTime,
        elapsedTime: this.elapsedTime
    };
    
    this.tasksService.postTasks(requestBody)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.time = res;
          //this.elapsed = res;
          console.log(this.time);
        },
        err => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks one more time! Could you have a look at this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63545220/how-to-post-mongodb-data-to-the-nested-array-using-node-js-and-express