# How to post MongoDB data to the nested array using NODE.js and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have been trying to post data from MongoDB to the user that is logged in. So whenever a user triggers a request to post data it should be sent and nested under that user.

router.post() method

```
router.post('/savetasks', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const { startTime, endTime, elapsedTime } = req.body;
  const newTime = new Time({startTime, endTime, elapsedTime});
  await newTime.save();

  const token = jwt.sign({ _id: newTime._id}, 'secretkey');

  res.status(200).json({token}); 

});
```

Using this method I can successfully save data in MongoDB but I don't understand how to get it nested under the specific user.

It should be like this:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
firstname: String,
lastname: String,
email: String,
password: String,
timings: [{
    startTime: String,
    endTime: String,
    elapsedTime: String
}]
});
```

I have tried different ways but all of them were giving me errors. The one way that gives me the most faith is actually with giving path '/posttasks/:_id', and assigning `add.function()` but since I am new in Mongo, Express, and Node.js I couldn't accomplish that

Angular code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { timer, from } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';
import { TasksService } from '../../services/tasks.service';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
 selector: 'app-private-tasks',
templateUrl: './private-tasks.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./private-tasks.component.css']
})
export class PrivateTasksComponent implements OnInit {

date:Date; 

times: number = 0;
display ;
interval;

time = [] as any;

tasks = [] as any;
user = [] as any;

startTime: any = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss', 'en');
endTime: any= formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss', 'en');
elapsedTime: any = formatDate(new Date(), 'HH:mm:ss', 'en'); 

constructor(
  private authService: AuthService,
  private tasksService: TasksService,
  private router: Router
) {

setInterval(() => {
  this.date = new Date()
}, 1000)
}




ngOnInit(): void {
  this.tasksService.getTasks1()
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.tasks = res; 
        console.log(this.tasks);
        
                   
      },
      err => console.log(err)
   );
}


startTimer() {  
  console.log("=====>");
  this.startTime = new Date();
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (this.times === 0) {
      console.log(this.startTime);
      this.times++;
    } else {
      this.times++;
    }
    this.display=this.transform( this.times)
  }, 1000);
}
transform(value: number) {
   var minutes: number =  Math.floor(value / 60);
   var hours : number = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
   return hours + ':' + minutes;
}

pauseTimer() {
  clearInterval(this.interval);

  this.endTime = new Date();
  //this.userID = new this.userID;
  console.log(this.endTime);

  const requestBody = {
    startTime: this.startTime,
    endTime: this.endTime,
    elapsedTime: this.endTime - this.startTime
};

  this.authService.postTasks({ requestBody })
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.time = res;
        console.log(this.time);
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
}
}
```

Comment: do you want to add or update the timings ?

Comment: @Kunal Mukherjee I need to add an array of results, every time when the user press the button it will add another index of an array(in this case "timings"), so when the user opens the page all the timings under that user will be posted

Comment: So every time the `/savetasks` API is called it will insert a fresh document right ?

Comment: @Kunal Mukherjee exactly, it will insert under the user that is logged-in at that moment. So the results will be an array of documents, and each document will have different timings apparently

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Model.prototype.update`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) in mongoose to update the sub-document `timings`.

However there exists two scenarios -

1. If you want to push entries without any need to check duplicates then use [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator

```
    var filter = {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('<USER_ID>')
    };
    
    var update = {
        $push: {
            timings: {
                startTime: "",
                endTime: "",
                elapsedTime: ""
            }
        }
    };
    
    db.collection.update(filter, update);
```

2. If you want to push only distinct entries then use [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator

```
    var filter = {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('<USER_ID>')
    };
    
    var update = {
        $addToSet: {
            timings: {
                startTime: "",
                endTime: "",
                elapsedTime: ""
            }
        }
    };
    
    db.collection.update(filter, update);
```

Note: Require `mongoose` first

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

---

Correct your code to the below, also you can't get the exact sub-document's Id, but you can get the updated root document -

```
const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body._id)
    },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            timings: {
                startTime, 
                endTime, 
                elapsedTime
            }
        }
    }, {
        new: true
    }).exec();
```

Comment: this is absolutely clear how to use $push or $addToSet operators. I have a problem how to get userID so that I can store data under that user

Comment: @MarkoMalbasic you just have to pass the `userId` of the user you wish to update in the filter, see the updated answer

Comment: "ReferenceError: mongoose is not defined" I am getting this error now ... I will play a bit! Thanks anyway

Comment: And now my question is   '<USER_ID>'   refers to what? How can I define it?

Comment: @MarkoMalbasic `UserId` is the `_id` of the current user, that you may get from your express controller like `req.body.userId` or angular app

Comment: I must be doing something completely wrong... I tried on so many ways but can't get it..

Comment: @MarkoMalbasic what are you stuck on ?

Comment: Check this line of code and tell me if i am wrong somewhere                                                     const newTime = User.update({_id: req.body._id}, {$addToSet: {timings: {startTime, endTime, elapsedTime}}});

Comment: "Cannot read property '_id' of null"  error, but wait... {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body._id)
    } refers to the ID of timings or the userSchema ?

Comment: It refers to the `_id` of the user schema, check what is passed from the front-end or the express app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220317/discussion-between-marko-malbasic-and-kunal-mukherjee).